# pandas str extract use regex to select all letters from a string only returning 1st match - str extract or regex issue?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

In Pandas I have a dataframe column called TermNew containing the following lowercase strings (please ignore bullet points - I was having trouble formatting)

**TermNew**

- 999 years from 1/01/2001
- 999 years (less 20 days) from 20/11/2000
- 99 years from 1/10/1979
- 999 years from 1/01/1992

Im trying to extract all letter characters (a-z only, no digits, no whitespace, no () or /) from TermNew into a new column Termtext with these expected outcomes

**Termtext**

- yearsfrom
- yearslessdaysfrom
- yearsfrom
- yearsfrom

Ive tried the following but its only returning letters up to the first white space i.e.

**leaseterm1['Termtext'] = leaseterm1['TermNew'].str.extract(r"([a-z]+)")**

**Outputs**

- years
- years
- years
- years

In regex101 I can use the global flag to match all letters correctly [See example](https://www.regex101.com/r/JIuyEf/1)

**Questions**

**1/ Is this a problem with str extract only finding the first match   or**

**2/ Is this a regex problem - I havent included any form of global search past the 1st whitespace?**

**Any suggestions gratefully received.   Thanks**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`str.extractall()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) instead and aggregate the results of multiple matches, as follows:

```
leaseterm1['Termtext'] = leaseterm1['TermNew'].str.extractall(r"([a-z]+)").groupby(level=0).agg(''.join)
```

or use [`GroupBy.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) for aggregation:

```
leaseterm1['Termtext'] = leaseterm1['TermNew'].str.extractall(r"([a-z]+)").groupby(level=0).sum(numeric_only=False)
```

**Result:**

```
print(leaseterm1)

                                    TermNew           Termtext
0                  999 years from 1/01/2001          yearsfrom
1  999 years (less 20 days) from 20/11/2000  yearslessdaysfrom
2                   99 years from 1/10/1979          yearsfrom
3                  999 years from 1/01/1992          yearsfrom
```

**Regarding to your questions:**

As you can see from the official doc of [`str.extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)

> For each subject string in the Series, extract groups **from the first
> match** of regular expression pat.

[`str.extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)  extracts the first match only.

If you want to extract for multiple matches, you should use [`str.extractall()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) instead.

For [`str.extractall()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html):

> For each subject string in the Series, extract groups **from all matches**
> of regular expression pat.

Comment: Thank you @SeaBean for the fast and helpful reply.

Comment: @pekoz1  Welcome!   In general, you can use  `str.extractall` to extract into a dataframe and also see the matches one by one.  Make good use of it.  :-)    Here, you want all matches joined together, hence we further aggregate them.  If not, you can separately manipulate the matches (maybe set into different columns, etc.)

Comment: @SeaBean Hi I have seen that you are very knowledgeable about pandas and data science. I couldn't find way to contact you privately. I am trying to make as many connections as I possibly can and learn from coders as I go along. If it is cool to personally message you about some questions please do let me know

Comment: @georgehere Thanks for your appreciation!  I think a good way to learn is by studying on other people's questions and answers here.  I also learned much by answering here.  Also learned from others' answers too!  For future questions regarding to Pandas, I think if it is related to some specific problems you face while practising  some works on it, you can post questions here.  Sure you will get lots of good answers from experts all around here in SO and learn from the answers if your question is clear and suitably  formatted.

Answer (score 2):

It is easier to replace all characters other than a-z

```
leaseterm1['Termtext'] = leaseterm1['TermNew'].str.replace(r"[^a-z]+", "")
```

Output

```
                                    TermNew           Termtext
0                  999 years from 1/01/2001          yearsfrom
1  999 years (less 20 days) from 20/11/2000  yearslessdaysfrom
2                   99 years from 1/10/1979          yearsfrom
3                  999 years from 1/01/1992          yearsfrom
```

Comment: Thank you @The fourth bird for the fast and helpful reply. Bedankt.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Luckily it is a well asked question with the expected output. It even has all those capital I's :-)

Comment: When I saw the question I did a double-take: surely the OP does not merely want to remove non-letters. Perhaps it's a lesson on avoiding an early commitment to the approach to be taken. You seem to have anticipated my comment. Not only capital "I"'s, but no "wanna"'s either.